# Angular 5: Validate multiple input fields by sum up values

Tags: angular, validation, angular5

I would like to validate multiple number input fields by sum up their values and create a custom Validator for Angular.

Every Input looks like this:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="10">
```

There are multiple number inputs and everyone can have a value between 0 and 10, but the sum of all fields must be less or equal 10.

I have a function that returns true if the sum of all input fields is less or equal 10. 
But how I achieve this with a custom Angular Validator? So that the error message appear instantly.

Comment: Do you want the error message to be under each input or at one place? Is there a fixed number of inputs or they can be dynamically added?

Comment: The inputs are dynamically, simply it's a list from a database. Where the error message appears does not really matter. The most important thing is that the message should appear instantly, when the sum is greater than 10.

Comment: If you're using a FormGroup, you can set a custom validator to the form itself (and not to the controls), and there you have all the input's value to sum up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like mentioned set validation on the group itself, so do for example:

```ts
this.myForm = fb.group({
  field1: [null],
  field2: [null]
  // more fields 
}, {validator: this.myValidator})
```

Then in your validator iterate the formcontrols in your group, sum up and return error or `null` based on valid or not:

```ts
myValidator(group: FormGroup) {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let a in group.controls) {
    sum += group.get([a]).value;
  }
  return sum > 10 ? { notValid: true} : null
}
```

and in template you can display error with:

```ts
*ngIf="myForm.hasError('notValid')"
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hzpn9j?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using reactive forms (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) as mentioned above you can create a custom validator which can be attached to the group like so

```
this.formbuilder.group({...}, { validator: someCustomValidator })
```

The custom validator would look something like this

```
export const numberMatcher = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} => 
{
  const number = control.get('number');
  const number2 = control.get('number2');
  return number + number2 < 10 ? null : { exceedsmax: true };
};
```

Which needs to be imported to your component (or exist inside of it)

```
  import { numberMatcher } from './numberMatcher';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
      number: ['', Validators.required],
      number2: ['', Validators.required],
     { validator: emailMatcher })
    });
  }
```

Then set up your form as normal making sure the formControlName matches the name being checked in the validator. You can then check as normal for the error i.e.

```
<div class="error" *ngIf="user.get('form').touched && user.get('form').hasError('exceededmax')">
  All fields must equal less than 10
</div>
```

for example. I think in essence this will solve your problem however will require some tweaking and adjustments from the very simple outline code I have written here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `FormGroup`

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
  field1: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
  field2: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
}, someCustomValidator);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it in angular 16 as the following:

in .ts file:

```
import {AbstractControl, ValidationErrors} from '@angular/forms';

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            control1: ['', [Validators.required]]
        }, {validators: this.sumUpValidator});

sumUpValidator(formGroup: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let a in formGroup.value) {
    sum += formGroup.value[a];
  }
  if (sum != 10) {
    return { sumUpValidator: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

in .html

```
<div *ngIf="form.errors?.sumUpValidator">
     The total value must be 10.
</div>
```