# Validate sum of reactive form elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a reactive form that is basically this.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      sections: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  addSection(){
    let section = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.sections;
    section.push(this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      items: this.fb.array([]),
      percentage: '',
    }));
  }
```

**addSection() is a function that adds an element to my `sections FormArray when i click something that's on my template`**

I sum up all percentages from every `section` inside the `sections formArray` and validate that it isn't bigger than 1 (I assume user is typing floating points in those specific inputs). Finally i want to disable the submit button at the end of the form if the sum if bigger than 1.

I tried the answer from this question but didn't work cause `https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706808/8579973` cause it was meant for a group of object thats all the same. I need it to validate just the "percentage" element from every group that is made.

I also tried to store the sum in local storage, but I don't want any extra button that triggers that procedure.

Thanks for your answers,
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this? **Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdgdv2

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormArray, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, ValidatorFn, Validators} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent{
  myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      sections: this.fb.array([], CustomValidator.checkPercentageSum)
    });
    this.addSection();
  }

  addSection(){
    let section = this.myForm.get('sections') as FormArray;
    section.push(this.fb.group({
      percentage: 0.2,
    }));
    section.push(this.fb.group({
      percentage: 0.3,
    }));
    section.push(this.fb.group({
      percentage: 1,
    }));

    console.log(this.myForm.valid , this.myForm.get('sections').errors);
    // Output: false {Invalid: true}
  }

}

//Custom Validator
export class CustomValidator {
  static checkPercentageSum(sections: FormArray): ValidationResult {
    if (sections) {
      let sumOfPercentages: number = 0;
      sections['controls'].forEach((sectionItem: FormGroup) => {
        sumOfPercentages = sectionItem['controls'].percentage.value + sumOfPercentages;
      });

      if (sumOfPercentages > 1) {
        return {"Invalid": true};
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}

export interface ValidationResult {
  [key: string]: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that is not what i need. Percentage is a % that the user decides. E.g., if the user creates 4 sections he could assign 0.25 (25%), to each, the result would be 100%. I just need to validate that the sum of control `percentage` of every sections that the user creates is not > 1

Comment: I think that is what my answer shows - a custom validator that will validate the sum of all percentage fields. The `addSection()` part you have to figure out. I just did multiple `section.push` for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Genius, this solves my problem ...  At first I didn't get those `section.push`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)